# About the definition of the closure of topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.

For $A\subset X$, one of the definitions of the closure of $ A$ is
$$cl(A):=\displaystyle\bigcap_{F \in \mathcal F_A} F , \ \mathrm{where} \ \mathcal F_A=\{ F \subset X \mid A \subset F,\ F : \mathrm{closed}\}.$$

My question ;

Does $\mathcal F_A \neq \emptyset$ hold for $A\neq \emptyset$ ?

If $A$ is closed, $A\in \mathcal F_A \neq \emptyset$ but does $\mathcal F_A\neq \emptyset$ also hold for non-closed set $A$ ?

I think the whole set $X$ is included in $\mathcal F_A$ since $A\subset X$ and $X$ is topological space so $X$ itself is closed, and thus $X \in \mathcal F_A \neq \emptyset.$

Is this idea correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $X \in \mathcal{F}_A$ for **any** $A$ so we're always taking the intersection of a non-empty family. Sometimes in that can happen that $\mathcal{F}_A = \{X\}$, $A$ is called dense in $X$ if this is the case.